# Check if date exists jQuery validator, ajax and CodeIgneter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am working on a site in CodeIgniter. I want to check if the date already exists in database. I have coded the required functionality but I am getting an error when submiting the form:

```
POST 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Here is my model:

```html
private function tanggal($date)
 {
  $this->db->where('start_date', $date);
  $query = $this->db->get('t_trx_activity');
  if( $query->num_rows() > 0 ){ return TRUE; } else { return FALSE; }
 }
```

My controller:

```html
function validate_date()
 {
 if (array_key_exists('start',$_POST)) {
 if ( $this->activity->tanggal($this->input->post('start')) == TRUE ) {
  echo false;;
  } else {
  echo true;
  }
  }
 }
```

My view:

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" id="form-date" role="form" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>activity/add">
<div class="form-group"> 
<label  class="col-sm-3 control-label">Start Date:<span
class="required">*</span> </label> 
<div class="col-sm-7"> 
<div class="input-group date date-picker" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
<input type="text"  class="form-control" readonly id="date" name="start" required>
<span class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
</span></div>
</div> 
</div> 
<div class="form-group"> 
    <label  class="col-sm-3 control-label">End Date:<span
    class="required">*</span> </label> 
<div class="col-sm-7"> 
<div class="input-group date date-picker" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
    <input type="text"  class="form-control" readonly name="end" required>
<span class="input-group-addon">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
</span></div>
 </div> 
</div> 
<button type="submit" class="btn green">
<i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Create</button>
```

jQuery Validation:

```js
var FormValidation = function () {

        var handleValidation = function() {

                var form    = $('#form-date');
                var error   = $('.alert-danger', form);
                var success = $('.alert-success', form);

                form.validate({
                    errorElement: 'span', //default input error message container
                    errorClass: 'help-block help-block-error', // default input error message class
                    focusInvalid: false, // do not focus the last invalid input
                    ignore: "", // validate all fields including form hidden input
                    rules: {
                        
                        start: {
                            required: true,
                            date: true,
                            remote: {
                                    url: "<?php echo site_url('activity/validate_date')?>",
                                    type: "post",
                                    data: {
                                                date: function(){ return $("#date").val(); }

                                            }
                                        }

                        },
                        end: {
                            required: true
                        },
                       
                    },

                     messages: {
                            start: 
                             {
                                    remote: 'Date already in use.'
                             }
                      },
```

Any Ideas about this how this can be solved?

Comment: maby `echo false;;` is the problem, open the route in a new page and see if it has any errors

Comment: Has any php error log??

Comment: Your model function `tanggal` must be `public` which is not `private`

Comment: POST http://localhost/weekly_report/activity/validate_date 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Use the $this->db->last_query(); and check execute or not the query. what is return query ?

Comment: this is because of you have error in your code

Comment: @ione Please find the error in php log and the php error should be like `[Wed Nov 02 14:52:00 2016] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx] PHP Fatal error:  Using $this when not in object context in /path/theError.php on line 225, referer: https://domain/theError.php`

Answer (score 0):

you are sending the post data as the name `date`in the ajax call, but you are receiving the data as name `start`,
try to change your controller function to the following,

```
function validate_date()
{
    if (array_key_exists('date',$_POST)) {
        if ( $this->activity->tanggal($this->input->post('date')) == TRUE ) {
           echo false;;
        } else {
            echo true;
        }
    }
}
```

or if u dont want to change the controller function, u can change the js code, change the data part in your remote function part in your jquery validator as follows,

```
data: {
     start: function(){ 
         return $("#date").val(); 
     }

}
```

Comment: if i data name 'start',what should i do?